# Couple quick SMTP Q's

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, smtp, smtpclient

So I'm currently 15, 2 months till I start my Cert III at Tafe doing Networking and hardware solutions then after that a Diploma in Networking. 
So far ive made simple little email programs in Visual Studio with Visual basic just using SMTP to email myself etc.

First Question: Is there some standard email receiving service like in command prompt or something? Not on a website? Can you make one?

Second Question: If I made a email receiving program or if a default one (cmd based) does exist can I connect my Rasspberry Pi to my Internet and run the server off it? 
I know some of these questions are retarded but I'm really new to this and wanted to ask some questions. 
Hope you don't mind!

Comment: First question: yes, yes and yes. Second question: no. **These questions are not programming related**, they are off topic here.

Comment: I am sorry, not my decision; it's part of SO. If SO is so toxic in your opinion then why are you here posting on this "toxic" site, just a question. Also SO has built a great community of very professional people from around the world that I can say will answer just about anything you are stuck with that is programming related.